# Exercise python: how to group element in a list?

Tags: python, list

I've tried to solve the following exercise, without using datetime!

Exercise:

> Given a list of int, such that the First three int represent a date,
>   the second three elementi represent a date etc..modify lst by grouping
>   every triple in One string with the numbers separeted by "/".

Example:

```
lst = [1, 2, 2013, 23, 9, 2011, 10, 11, 2000]
groupd(lst)
lst
['1/2/2013', '23/9/2011', '10/11/2000']
```

My attempt:

```
lst = [1, 2, 2013, 23, 9, 2011, 10, 11, 2000]. 
stri = str(lst).   

def groupd(lst):. 
cont = 1. 
a = (stri.replace(',', '/')).  
    for x in lst:. 
        if len[x]>2:.                
            lst.insert(lst[0],a )].   
                print(a).          
print(groupd(lst)).
```

PS: sorry for my english!! Thank you all!

Comment: Why do you have periods/full stops at the end of each line? This will make your program not run. Python's line terminator is a newline, not `.` or `;` or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to create tuples and then format them to your strings:

```
>>> ['%d/%d/%d' % parts for parts in zip(lst[::3], lst[1::3], lst[2::3])]
['1/2/2013', '23/9/2011', '10/11/2000']
```

Starting from an offset (first argument to slicing) while skipping items (third argument to slicing) allows for windowing behavior.

More generically:

```
>>> N = 3
>>> ['/'.join(['%d'] * N) % parts for parts in zip(*[lst[start::N] for start in range(N)])]
['1/2/2013', '23/9/2011', '10/11/2000']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the list by it's index using `groupby` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby
['/'.join(str(i[1]) for i in g) for _, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key = lambda x: x[0]/3)]

# ['1/2/2013', '23/9/2011', '10/11/2000']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a functional approach where the answer is passed around with the recursive function.

```
lst1 = [1, 2, 2013, 23, 9, 2011, 10, 11, 2000] 
lst2 = []
lst3 = [1,2, 2015]
lst4 = [1,2]
lst5 = [1]
lst6 = [1,2,2013, 23, 9]

def groupToDate(lst, acc): 
    if len(lst) < 3:
        return acc
    else:
        # take first elements in list
        day = lst[0]
        month = lst[1]
        year = lst[2]
        acc.append(str(day) + '/' + str(month) + '/' + str(year))
        return groupToDate(lst[3:len(lst)], acc)


print(groupToDate(lst1, []))
print(groupToDate(lst2, []))
print(groupToDate(lst3, []))
print(groupToDate(lst4, []))
print(groupToDate(lst5, []))
print(groupToDate(lst6, []))
```

It's also the basic approach of solving such problem if you don't want to use list comprehensions or groupby